# Is there any way to disable Alert Boxes on Visual Studio Comunity Edition 2022

Tags: python, c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio doesn't support Python 3.12 yet, but to let you know this, VS shows an alert box like this:

[image: Alert Box in Question]

I was wondering if there is any way to disable this pop up?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/issues/7759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to go away, you can open the .pyproj and change the Interpreter Version from 0.0 to 3.12.

Reference from: https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/issues/7759